# Is there an alternative way to add cases for redux slices?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

The issue I have is handling the `addCase` for each of the async calls. For every async call I have, do I need to keep adding the pending and fulfilled cases to the `builder` under `extraReducers` or is there another way?

Code for context:

```
export const counterSlice = createSlice({
...
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(incrementAsync.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'loading'
        console.log(action);
      })
      .addCase(incrementAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle'
        state.value += action.payload
        console.log(action);
      })
      .addCase(getWorkouts.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'loading'
        console.log(action);
      })
      .addCase(getWorkouts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle'
        state.data = action.payload
        console.log(action);
      })
      // ... and so on?
  },
})
```

where `incrementAsync` and `getWorkouts` are async thunks:

```
export const incrementAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  FETCH_COUNT,
  async (amount: number) => {
    const response = await fetchCount(amount)
    
    // The value we return becomes the `fulfilled` action payload
    return response.data
  }
)

export const getWorkouts = createAsyncThunk(
  FETCH_WORKOUTS,
  async (payload: { userId: string, date: Date }) => {
    const response = await getWorkoutsAsync(payload.userId, payload.date);

    // The value we return becomes the `fulfilled` action payload
    return response;
  }
)
```